# How do I log trace id in Java Spring @Async thread

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, logback

I have a rest request coming in to a spring controller. And at the end of all the operations invoking an @Async method.

Parent request log:

```
2022-11-18 15:23:31,660 [35m[http-nio-3001-exec-8][0;39m TRACE-ID=[**dcb803cb074a4e71ab4f9f43aa3c2ca1**] X-CLIENT-ID=[mfs-reformer] [39mTRACE[0;39m org.zalando.logbook.Logbook#21 - ffd7568a55ae8519 Some log...
```

Async request log:

```
2022-11-18 15:12:09,930 [35m[Async-1][0;39m TRACE-ID=[] X-CLIENT-ID=[] [34mINFO [0;39m a.a.m.r.s.SculptService#55 - Some log...
```

I need to log the parent request trace id in this async method

logback appender:

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
  <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
    <pattern>%date %magenta([%thread]) TRACE-ID=[%X{TRACE-ID}] X-CLIENT-ID=[%X{X-CLIENT-ID}] %highlight(%-5level) %logger{36}#%line - %msg%n</pattern>
  </layout>
</appender>
```